# Read External List (BCS) Data in SharePoint Hosted App

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, bcs, external-list

I have this SharePoint hosted app on SharePoint Online. In this app, I am able to read the data from any SharePoint List/Library using the REST calls. However, when I try to fetch the items from a external list, I keep getting the Access denied error.

This external list is pulling the data from the Azure SQL Server using the BCS model. I can view all the data when I click on the List in the browser, but unable to fetch the same using the REST APIs.

Here's what I have tried so far:

- On the Azure side, I have added an ip range of, 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 to the sql server's firewall. (Again, it's a test envr so I just gave everything.) :)
- Have also configured the, 'Manage connections to online services' for BCS on the -admin page.
- For the app, have given it the read permission for BCS.
- On the 'Do you trust this app' page, I am selecting the given BCS connection also.
  But when the rest call is being executed it's throwing the access denied exception!

Here's my code snippet:

```
var headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
    "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
};

//First tried GETITEMS
url = appWebUrl + "/_api/Sp.AppContextSite(@target)/Web/Lists(guid'" + listID + "')/getitems?$select=" + fields + "&@target='" + hostWebUrl + "'" ;

//Also tried ITEMS
url = appWebUrl + "/_api/Sp.AppContextSite(@target)/Web/Lists(guid'" + listID + "')/items?$select=" + fields + "&@target='" + hostWebUrl + "'" ;

var payload = {
    'query': {
        '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' },
        'ViewXml': '<View><Query>' + query.ViewQuery + '</Query></View>'
    }

var ajaxOptions =
{
    url: url,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.body) {
            var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
            dfd.resolve(jsonObject);
        }
        else
            dfd.resolve();
    },
    error: function (sender) {
        dfd.reject(sender);
    }
};

ajaxOptions.body = JSON.stringify(payload);

var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appWebUrl);
executor.executeAsync(ajaxOptions);
```

Following is the permission set given to the app:

```
<AppPermissionRequests>
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="Write"/>
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/bcs/connection" Right="Read" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

My question here is, is it possible to pull the BCS data, using REST APIs in a SharePoint hosted app? Plz advice.